# There is no natural polynomial map (other than $1$) that can eventually leave the $k$-semiprimes behind.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, monoid, twin-primes

Let $F(S)$ be the free commutative monoid on countably many symbols $S$.  Then it's obvious that $F(S) = \{1\} \uplus S \uplus S^2 \uplus \dots$

One can take $S = $ the prime numbers in $\Bbb{N}$ in which case $F(S) = \Bbb{N}$ itself.

It's also obvious that $S^i S^j$ done elementwise is equal to $S^{i +j}$ for all $i, j \in \Bbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ if we let $S^0 = \{1\}$.

Suppose that $R = F(S) \cup \{0\}$ has the additional structure of a semiring in which $+$ is compatible with the free monoid $\cdot$ in a distributive way as in $\Bbb{N} \cup \{0\}$.

Let $f : R \to R$ be any semiring polynomial such as $f(n) = n + 1$.

Then consider the set $X_i$ of any such $f$ such that $f$ is eventually free of smaller sets $S^k, k=1..i$.  That is to say that $f \in X_i \iff $ there exists $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $m \geq n \implies f(m) \notin S^k, k=1..i$.

We do not know if $f(n) = n(n+2)$ is in the set $X_2$.  If it is in $X_2$, then clearly twin primes is false since that would mean that $n(n+2) \notin S^2$.

We do know, however, that $1(n) = 1$ is in each $X_i$ since $1 \notin $ any $S^i$ automatically.    Similarly we know that if $f \in X_i$ and $i \geq 2$ that $f \in X_{i-1}$ as anything eventually outside of a larger set is eventually outside any smaller set.  Thus we have:

$$
X_1 \supset X_2 \supset \dots
$$

What must be at the end of this chain?  It must be the trivial monoid $X_{\infty} = \{1(n)\}$.   This is because there are no numbers outside of all numbers that are not $1$.

---

Each $X_i$ forms a monoid.  Let $f(n) \in X_i, g(n) \in X_j$.  Then there exists $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $m \geq n \implies f(m) \in \{1\} \cup S^{i+1} \cup S^{i+2} \cup \dots$ and similarly for $n'$ and $g$.  Then by nature of polynomial maps, $f(n) \neq 1$ eventually.  That means that $f(n) \in S^{i+1} \cup S^{i+2} \cup \dots$ eventually and similarly goes for $g$.  Together this means that $f(n) g(n) \in S^{i + j + 2} \cup S^{i + j + 3} \cup S^{i + j + 4 } \dots \subset \cup S^{i + j + 1} \cup S^{i + j + 2} \cup \dots$

Clearly this means that $fg \in X_{i+j} \subset X_i, X_j$.  Thus, all $X_i$ are monoids.

---

But since $X_i \ni 1$ we have that $X_i = X_i X_i \subset X_{2i}$. $X_{1} \subset X_2$ when we know $X_2 \subset X_1$ already, thus $X_1 = X_2$.  Similarly $X_2 \subset X_2 X_1 \subset X_3$ and so on...  Therefore all these monoids equal $\{1(n)\}$ the trivial monoid!

Therefore, the twin prime conjecture is true by construction.

$f(n) = n(n+2)$ cannot eventually leave behind $S^2 = $ the products of two primes, because the only polynomial natural map that does that is $1(n)$!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @CedricMartens it's whether or not the proof if is valid.  I've not only outlined but I've proved all statements.  It's therefore very elementary, but looks legit to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

> Then by nature of polynomial maps, $f(n) \neq 1$ eventually.

This isn't true for $1(n)=1$.

Comment: I proved that $X_i X_j \subset X_{i + j}$ which contains $X_{2i}$ case as a special case.   And $X_i$ is a monoid.  For any monoid $M$, we have $MM = M$.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond: You're right; I'd overlooked that; the error is already in the proof for $X_i X_j \subset X_{i + j}$; I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think that's not the flaw.  I'm saying that $1(n)$ is the only such map!  I think the flaw is that $f(n) = n^k$ eventually leaves behind all $P^1 \cup \dots \cup P^{k-1}$.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond: I don't see why it matters that $1(n)$ is the only such map. You try to prove $X_i X_j \subset X_{i + j}$, which is clearly not true. It would be true if these sets didn't contain $1(n)$, but they do, so their product contains products of $1(n)$ with all their elements, and thus contains all their elements, which are generally not in $X_{i+j}$.

Comment: $1(n)1(n) = 1(n) = 1$ though.. So

Comment: Do you think the proof can be repaired?

Comment: $f(n) = 1(n) = 1 \implies f(n) g(n) = g(n) \in X_i$ though so could have been a case I skipped.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond: No, I don't think it can be repaired. I think if there were such an elementary proof of the twin prime conjecture, it would have been found long ago.

Answer (score 0):

The flaw is. Let $k \in \Bbb{N}$ be greater than $1$.

$f(n) = n^k$ eventually leaves all $S^1 \cup \dots \cup S^{k-1}$.  Thus we must admit powers of $n$ into $X_i$.  Surely, this invalidates the proof for now.

Comment: I see neither where you introduced $P^i$, nor why admitting powers of $n$ into $X_i$ is a problem.

Comment: @joriki I edited.  It's a problem because I supposedly proved all $X_i = \{ 1\}$ while these power maps exist in $X_1, X_2, \dots$.